# Compiling swc with sources or only with asdoc

Tags: flex4, flash-builder, swc, asdoc

How to compile swc-library with documentation (**asdoc**) and sources in *Flash Builder 4.6*? If I compile *Flex-application* I can set check *compile with sources*, but for the *library project* I don't have this option.

Are there some option for flex compiler, which can be added to asdoc documentation?

Answer (score 0):

When you make a library project, you will right click the source files you want to add, and click 'Include Class in Library'. Then you can export a swc and all of your chosen files will be compiled into it.

Comment: it is such as FlexLib project propetries -> Flex build path -> Clases. There are I can add or remove classes from swc. But documentation is unavailable after export. I can see documentation only if I keep FlexLib project opened.